# ReactJS - Proper way to get a result of dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

For async requests, I'm using `redux-saga`.

In my component, I call an action to recover the user password, it its working but I need a way to know, **in my component**,  that the action I dispatched was successfully executed, like this:

**success** below is returning:

```
payload: {email: "test@mail.com"}
type: "@user/RecoverUserPasswordRequest"
__proto__: Object
```

**My component:**

```
async function onSubmit(data) {
    const success = await dispatch(recoverUserPasswordRequestAction(data.email))
    if (success) {
      // do something
    }
  }
```

**My actions.js**

```
export function recoverUserPasswordRequest(email) {
  return {
    type: actions.RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
    payload: { email },
  }
}

export function recoverUserPasswordSuccess(email) {
  return {
    type: actions.RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
    payload: { email },
  }
}

export function recoverUserPasswordFailure() {
  return {
    type: actions.RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_FAILURE,
  }
}
```

**My sagas.js**

```
export function* recoverUserPassword({ payload }) {
  const { email } = payload

  try {
    const response = yield call(api.patch, 'user/forgot-password', {
      email
    })

    // response here if success is only a code 204
    console.log('response', response)

    yield put(recoverUserPasswordSuccess(email))

  } catch (err) {
    toast.error('User doesnt exists');
    yield put(recoverUserPasswordFailure())
  }
}

export default all([
  takeLatest(RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_REQUEST, recoverUserPassword),
])
```

In my **reducer.js** I dont have nothing related to recover the user's password, like a `RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_SUCCESS` because like I said, the api response from my saga is only a code 204 with no informations

Comment: you shouldn't expect a return value from a dispatched action. The flow of redux is to dispatch an action, update a reducer/s, and the connected reducer now holds the updated value.

Comment: If you don't want to make a reducer, why not just return the status code instead of the email from your action (or both) back to your component?

Comment: thats a good idea, how can I return the status code to my component? I have to save it first in my reducer and then use useSelector in my component?

Comment: Hmm, I'm looking at it now and I'm not sure. I'm not using sagas, but I was able to just `return res.status`, instead of dispatching to a reducer from my action, and pick up the status returned in my component. If you return without a `type` in your action, that still goes to the reducer? If that is the case, are you able to create a normal action that is not linked to sagas and just return straight to the component? I think the proper way would be to just create a reducer as someone already suggested though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat this as a state change in your application.

Add a reducer that receives these actions `RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_SUCCESS` or `RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_FAILURE`, then updates the store with information about request status. For example:

```js
const initialState = {
   email: null,
   status: null,
}

const recoverPasswordReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    //...
    if (action.type === actions.RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_SUCCESS) {
        return {...initialState, status: True }
    }
    if (action.type === actions.RECOVER_USER_PASSWORD_SUCCESS) {
        return {...initialState, status: False }
    }
    return state;
}
```

You can later have status as one of the fields selected in mapStateToProps when connect the component that needs to know about the status of the operation to the store.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
       /* ... other fields needed from state */
       status: state.status
   }
}

export connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentNeedsToKnow)
```